# Совместимые версии spring + spring data + mongodb driver?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, maven, spring-data

**Не spring boot**

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие последние версии будут совместимы для трех следующих зависимостей:

`spring framework (context, etc.)`

`spring-data-mongodb`

`mongodb driver¿`

Относительно драйвера для mongo: там есть несколько артефактов - `mongodb-java-driver`, `mongodb-driver`, async и другие, какой следует выбрать для корректной работы?

Уже два дня пытаюсь запустить приложение, на последних версиях (все на последних), пишет nosuchmethiderror, думаю проблема в совместимости

Comment: а не проще через спринг бут. зайдите на сайт https://start.spring.io/ , добавляйте нужные зависимости, включая монго , скачивайте проект...

Comment: Либо можете прописать [BOM](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#bill-of-materials-bom-poms). Например, [Spring Data BOM](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-bom).

Comment: Попробуйте как в официальном [примере](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/main/bom/pom.xml)

Comment: Spring boot для слабаков)) я шучу, просто спринг бут не позволит мне разобраться во всем если я не буду знать как оно конфигурируется

Comment: BOM было полезно, но это не дает ответа на зависимость mongo-java-driver, не зависящую от spring ecosystem

Comment: В теории Вам нужна зависимость `mongodb-driver-sync`, либо `mongodb-driver-reactivestreams`. Зависимости `mongo-java-driver` и `mongodb-driver` являются устаревшими.

Comment: Относительно драйверов можете почитать [тут](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/driver/getting-started/installation/) и [тут](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.8/driver-async/getting-started/installation/)